# How to create dynamic URLs with query string from Custom Google Search?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

Ok, so I have a website that features a custom google search engine (see here: http://www.veegle.net/). Currently the URL is static, but I would like for the search terms to show up as a query string in a dynamic URL, so I can link people to search results.

So, for instance, if someone searches for "potatoes", I'd like the URL to become something like: `http://www.veegle.net/search?q=potatoes`

I'm a newb with no real programming knowledge, so if anyone can set me in the right direction, I'd hugely appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "queryParameterName=" param in your Custom Search element. E.g.

```
<gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="http://www.example.com" newWindow="true" queryParameterName="search">
```

will create urls like:
http://www.example.com?search=my+search+term

Is is described here:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#customizing